User Navigation in Telegram Mini App Back and Forth for the same Telegram bot
I'm developing a Telegram mini app and facing a challenge. I need the app to let users return to the bot, send a video, and then reopen the mini app without reloading it. I tried using openTelegramLink, but it doesn't work with the bot that opened the mini app. Does anyone know how to achieve this or have any alternative solutions?

dear viewers would you be so kind to leave some feedback in case of down vote, thanks

If you want the user to talk with the same bot instead of opening the link, you should may be just close() the Mini App.
Later, to re-open to the correct stage you may want to use a deep link parameter. I think the initData or initDataUnsafe.start_param inside the  window.Telegram.WebApp object can help you on this.
I personally haven't built a Mini App, but from the documentation I can see you can use deep links such as the following to do the same:
https://t.me/botusername/appname?startapp=command

Make sure to check the official documentation for more details: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-mini-apps
Hope this helps :)

Thanks for your answer, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for. In case of reopen I have to load the app (takes some time). On the other hand if you use openTelegramLink the mini app is still open (no need to load it once again) and the switch back is very fast.

I can not find the appropriate solution and have to open another bot connected to the same backend to accept a video, this way return opens a mini app without reload.
